# error "Font 'tty' is not defined

Tags: fonts

I am running on Ubuntu 18.10 and emacs 25.2,

I changed the default font to

```
(set-default-font "Monaco 14")
```

but get error report as:

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Font ‘tty’ is not defined")
  modify-frame-parameters(#<frame ~/Documents/Pubrepo/Algorithms/Algorithms_Wiley/graph_BFS.py 0x10d2c30> ((display . ":0") (minibuffer . t) (frameset--mini t) (frameset--id . "653D-A79A-BCEA-2E8C") (internal-border-width . 0) (unsplittable) (modeline . t) (width . 140) (height . 76) (font . "tty") (border-color . "#424242") (background-color . "#000000") (menu-bar-lines . 0) (vertical-scroll-bars) (tool-bar-lines . 0) (cursor-color . "#d54e53") (foreground-color . "#eaeaea") (background-mode . dark) (display-type . color)))
```

I googled but found no such a font tty.

How could I solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set-default-font` is deprecated:

> This function is obsolete since 23.1;
>   use `set-frame-font` instead.

You can just change it to something like this:

```
(set-frame-font "Monaco-14")
```

Comment: thank you, I learned from your answer, but this time it report error `Error (frameset): Font ‘tty’ is not defined`

Comment: Are you using Emacs in a terminal?

Comment: `(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist
             '(font . "Monaco-13"))
` works. thank you very much.